# uninitialized constant CarrierWave::Storage::Fog with Google Cloud Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, fog, sitemap-generator-gem

I have seen lots of other people having similar problems to me but none of the listed solutions apply so I am hoping this awesome community can help me out.

I am trying to use the sitemap_generator gem but I host with Heroku so I am trying to follow their documentation [here](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator/wiki/Generate-Sitemaps-on-read-only-filesystems-like-Heroku) to use Carrierwave to upload the sitemaps to Google Cloud Storage. I am already using Google Cloud to upload my images with all works fine so I was hoping it would be straightforward however the files are not being uploaded. The documentation says you need to add:

```
config.storage = :fog
```

To your carrierwave config file however whenever I add it, I get the following error:

```
gems/carrierwave-49fdad1ec6ca/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:75:in `eval': uninitialized constant CarrierWave::Storage::Fog (NameError)
```

My Carrierwave config looks like this:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
     config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/"
     config.storage = :fog
     config.fog_credentials = {
         :provider => 'Google'
     }
     config.fog_directory = 'bucket-name'
     config.asset_host = 'https://domain.storage.googleapis.com'
end
```

(fog_directory and asset_host are replaced with dummy values)

And in my gem file I have:

```
gem 'fog'
gem 'carrierwave', github: 'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'
```

I have seen a lot of people using AWS with the same error but their solution is to change to use fog gem instead of fog-aws (which I am already doing) and require fog/aws. I have tested this like so:

```
gem 'fog', require: 'fog/google'
```

But still have the same issue.

Can anyone suggest what I can do to try and resolve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error using fog-aws for Amazon S3. It seems this error occurs if storage is fog, doesn't matter it's amazon s3 or google cloud.

I used carrierwave gem to upload user profile picture so I solved this by moving storage configuration after credentials configuration as below:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  if Rails.env.staging? || Rails.env.production?
    config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'
    config.fog_credentials = {
      provider: 'AWS',
      aws_access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
      region: ENV['AWS_REGION']
    }
    config.storage = :fog
    config.fog_directory = ENV['S3_BUCKET']
    config.fog_public    = true
    config.fog_attributes = { cache_control: "public, max-age=#{365.days.to_i}" }
  else
    config.storage = :file
    config.enable_processing = Rails.env.development?
  end
end
```

Another solution was to add `require 'carrierwave/storage/fog'` at the top, in above file. For me the file was carrier_wave.rb under initializers directory.

Adding links where I found above solutions.

[Medium](https://medium.com/@pk60905/use-carrierwave-to-upload-files-to-s3-81ce79c29b6d) [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/2023) [Fog](https://github.com/fog/fog/issues/3429)

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is 7 months old but i just wasted 36h trying to implement that same gem... no luck. It seems that documentation is slightly outdated.

If you ask me, `fog-google` is unnecessary at this point!

Try this gem for CarrierWaveUploader integration with google.

[carrierwave-google-storage github](https://github.com/metaware/carrierwave-google-storage)